# JavaScript count function

Tags: javascript, loops, count

I'm trying to wring a script that outputs an array and counts the number of elements in the array based on user input.

```
<script>
    // Function searches a given array and counts the number of times an element appears in the array.
    function countOccurences(numArray, num) // function
        {                           //parameters
            var count = 0;

            if(array[i] == 2)
            count++;
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var num = [2, 6, 33, 1, 77, 2, 98]; <!-- array -->
document.write("<p>"+nums.toString()+"</p>"); <!-- fill the array-->
var count = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter number to search for", "")); <!--ask for the numer to search -->
// linear search
var p = countOccurences(nums, key) ;

document.write("<p>Value "+p+" was not found in array </p>"); //output the count

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not Java (and you forgot the language tag anyway). Also you didn't ask an actual question or explain what's wrong with this code

Comment: And what's the question? P.S. `<!-- ... -->` - wrong comments for JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a couple of things. first, your function doesnt actually cycle through the array, so it cant actually search the for the target value. if you want to get a value out of a function, you need to return that value inside the function

```
<script>
    function countOccurences(numArray, num) 
        {                           
            var count = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++  ){
               if (numArray[i] == target) count++
            }
            return count
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't forget to ask an actual question. Assuming you're asking to make your script work, this should do the trick.

```
    function countOccurences(numsArr, target){
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < numsArr.length; i++  ){
            if (numsArr[i] == target) count++
        }
        return count;
    }
    const nums = [2, 6, 33, 1, 77, 2, 98];  
    const target = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter number to search for", ""))
    const count = countOccurences(nums, target) //  you can output count in whatever way you like.
```